# How to make modal get value from button inside a while

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wrote a while loop were it displays the picture that I have kept and I want when the user presses the button in the picture to popup a modal with the picture in it. This is the code that i wrote to display the products and when he presses the button then "onclick" it sets a session were I store the image of the picture and I display on the modal but that does not work. It only takes the last picture that is displayed. How do I make it to display the picture that I select?

```
<?php
$query_name="SELECT * FROM products WHERE active='1' ";
$result =  mysqli_query($conn, $query_name);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    ?>

    <div class="block2">
        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
            <img  src="img/<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?> " alt="">

            <button href="#" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['what_picture']=$rows['picture']; ?>" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                Quick View
            </button>
        </div>

            
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

This is the modal

```
<div class="wrap-modal1 js-modal1 p-t-60 p-b-20">
    <div class="overlay-modal1 js-hide-modal1"></div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="bg0 p-t-60 p-b-30 p-lr-15-lg how-pos3-parent">
            <button class="how-pos3 hov3 trans-04 js-hide-modal1">
                <img src="images/icons/icon-close.png" alt="CLOSE">
            </button>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-7 p-b-30">
                    <div class="p-l-25 p-r-30 p-lr-0-lg">
                        <div class="wrap-slick3 flex-sb flex-w">
                            <div class="wrap-slick3-dots"></div>
                            <div class="wrap-slick3-arrows flex-sb-m flex-w"></div>

                            <div class="slick3 gallery-lb">
                                <div class="item-slick3" data-thumb="images/product-detail-01.jpg">
                                    <div class="wrap-pic-w pos-relative">
                                        <img src="img/<?php echo $_SESSION['what_picture']; ?>" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

                                        <a class="flex-c-m size-108 how-pos1 bor0 fs-16 cl10 bg0 hov-btn3 trans-04" href="images/product-detail-01.jpg">
                                            <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All the PHP runs on the server before anything is sent to the client. The loop is overwriting the session variable each time. You need to use AJAX if you want clicking on something to update a PHP variable.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript vanilla or jQuery do that I can draft some code for you

Comment: @Barmar how do i do that

Answer (score 1):

You have to do ajax for targeted element and show in model

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you're making here is in this link

```
onclick="<?php $_SESSION['what_picture']=$rows['picture']; ?>"
```

The problem here is, in the onclick attribute you are not calling any JavaScript function. What you need to fix this is, call a function with the **$rows['picture']** as a parameter to it.

E.g.

```
onclick="setModelPicture(<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?>)"
```

In addition to that, you need to do 2 things.

1. Give an "id" to the image that we want to target

> img id="**dynamic-model-picture**" alt="IMG-PRODUCT"

2. Need to define the following JavaScript function to set the image inside the model to what you're passing in to the function setModelPicture.

> ```
> function setModelPicture(picture){
>    document.getElementById("dynamic-model-picture").src = picture;
> }
> ```

In the above scenario, whenever the user clicks on the image, the path of the picture (I believe is in **$rows['picture']**) get passed in to the **setModelPicture** function and from there it updates the image src attribute.

Comment: I wrote 
<img id="dynamic-model-picture" src="img/<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?> " alt="">

<button href="#" onclick="setModelPicture(<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?>)" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
   Quick View
</button>

and on the end of the code i added the script that you provided, now what do I write to the img path of the modal?

Comment: @demetris Initially you don't have to set the image path of the img element inside the model. What should happen is, whenever the user clicks on the "Quick View" button, that will trigger the setModelPicture function and send the image path as the parameter. Inside the function, it will set the image "src" attribute inside the model to view the image. 

In your button, you should enclose the image path with quotes. E.g. <button href="#" onclick="setModelPicture('<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?>')" ...